# Error en C++. thread no está definido

Tags: c++, hilos

Estoy intentando crear un hilo que ejecute una función. Pero cuando declaro el hilo me dice que thread no está definido. Este es el código que intento ejecutar.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void saludo();

int main(void) {

  thread hilo1(saludo);
  hilo1.join();

  return 0;
}

void saludo() {
  std::cout << "Hola mundo";
}
```

Y esta es una captura del error que me lanza.
[image: Error en C++. El identificador thread no está definido]

**Edito:**

He añadido el using namespace std como me comentaron en una respuesta, pero el error sigue persistiendo.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿ Porque haces `std::cout` y, sin embargo, **no indicas el namespace** para referirte a `thread` ?

Comment: Por qué todavía no hemos llegado a los namespace. No sé como funcionana

Comment: pon `using namespace std;` arriba, luego usa al `thread` como `std::thread`

Comment: El primer comentario (probablemente) se refería a que usaste `std::cout` pero no `std::thread`. Por eso te lo preguntaba.

Comment: HE usado std::thread pero me dice que thread no es un miembro de std. También me dice que hilo1 no está declarado. Pero eso se deberá al problema con thread

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon qué versión de C++ y qué compilador estás utilizando. Lo último que mencionaste es un problema muuuy distinto.

Comment: Es importante que nos menciones la versión de C++ que estás utilizando.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta e indica el estado actual del código **y el error que te da el compilador** (no el error que te indica el IDE). `thread` pertenece al *namespace* `std`. Pero `<thread>` solo está incluido a partir de C++11. Por lo tanto, es **imposible** que tengas puesto `using namespace std;` al principio del archivo, no te de errores de *include*, y si te de errores de identificador no definido.

Comment: ... Salvo que estés compilando con alguna versión reducida, como, por ejemplo, para Arduino. Todos los detalles son importantes; es importante proporcionar los máximos posibles.

Comment: Como puedo saber que versión de C++ estoy usando?

Answer (score 0):

El error vendría a ser que estás definiendo mal a `thread`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tendrías que cambiarlo por `std::thread`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void saludo();

int main(void) {

  std::thread hilo1(saludo);
  hilo1.join();

  return 0;
}

void saludo() {
  std::cout << "Hola mundo";
}
```

**Salida:**

```
// Hola mundo
```

Cabe recalcar que esto no funciona en todas las versiones de gcc.

https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11

Podrías utilizar [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread.html) si el error persiste.

Comment: He probado con std::thread y con boost::thread. Con el primero me daba el mismo error. Con boost me sale "un nombre seguido de '::' debe ser un nombre de clase o espacio de nombres"

Comment: En mi caso si funcionó, debe ser más que nada por la versión que utilizas.

Comment: @MoisesMS revisa esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519607/stdthread-error-thread-not-member-of-std